# Windows SetupAPI DIF_REMOVE usage

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, windows-xp

I'm trying to entirely disable the keyboard using the windows SetupAPI.

At present I can remove the keyboard successfully with no issues using the DIF_REMOVE function like so:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string keyboard_device_instance_path("<my_path_here>"); // Win7

HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = ::SetupDiGetClassDevs(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);

SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
::ZeroMemory(&DeviceInfoData, sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
DWORD DeviceIndex = 0;
std::vector<char> DeviceInstanceId(128, '\0');
DWORD RequiredSize = 0;

// Query all devices
while (::SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(DeviceInfoSet, DeviceIndex++, &DeviceInfoData))
{
    // Find the Keyboard
    if (::SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceIdA(DeviceInfoSet, &DeviceInfoData, &DeviceInstanceId[0], DWORD(DeviceInstanceId.size()), &RequiredSize))
    {
        if (keyboard_device_instance_path == &DeviceInstanceId[0])
        {
            std::cout << "Breaking keyboard\n";
            if (!SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_REMOVE, DeviceInfoSet, &DeviceInfoData))
            {
                std::cerr << "Failed to remove keyboard: " << ::GetLastError() << '.' << std::endl;
            }
}
```

After disabling it, I want to re-enable the keyboard when a condition is met. For this I naturally looked to 'DIF_UNREMOVE' but have had no success.

Here is the code that attempts to re-enable the keyboard:

```
SP_UNREMOVEDEVICE_PARAMS UnRemoveParams;
                UnRemoveParams.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = sizeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER);
                UnRemoveParams.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DIF_UNREMOVE;
                UnRemoveParams.Scope = DI_UNREMOVEDEVICE_CONFIGSPECIFIC;
                UnRemoveParams.HwProfile = 0;

                if (::SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(DeviceInfoSet, &DeviceInfoData, &UnRemoveParams.ClassInstallHeader, sizeof(UnRemoveParams)))
                {
                    std::cout << "Fixing keyboard\n";
                    if (!SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_UNREMOVE, DeviceInfoSet, &DeviceInfoData))
                    {
                        std::cerr << "Failed to re-enable keyboard: " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
                    }
                }
```

This code is used in the while loop immediately after the removal code. I get an error "No such device installed". What is the correct way to do this? I can only use headers supported by windowsXP

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by instead re-enumerating the systems hardware devices like so:

```
        DWORD pdnDevInst = 0;
        if (CM_Locate_DevNodeA(PDEVINST(&pdnDevInst), NULL, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL) != CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to revive keyboard\n";
        }
        else if (CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(pdnDevInst, CM_REENUMERATE_NORMAL) != CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to revive keyboard: Renumerate dev node Error\n";
        }
```